# Undefined Index PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I have been trying to get a form in HTML/PHP to process to into mysql / phpmyadmin table which is on the numyspace server but for reasons unknown to myself i get the following error message.

> Notice: Undefined index: Username in
>   /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11034582/public_html/CaseProject/registerUserProcess.php
>   on line 14
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Forename in
>   /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11034582/public_html/CaseProject/registerUserProcess.php
>   on line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Surname in
>   /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11034582/public_html/CaseProject/registerUserProcess.php
>   on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Address in
>   /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11034582/public_html/CaseProject/registerUserProcess.php
>   on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined index: PostCode in
>   /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11034582/public_html/CaseProject/registerUserProcess.php
>   on line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined index: EmailAddress in
>   /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11034582/public_html/CaseProject/registerUserProcess.php
>   on line 19
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Password in
>   /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11034582/public_html/CaseProject/registerUserProcess.php
>   on line 20
>
> Notice: Undefined index: DateOfCreation in
>   /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11034582/public_html/CaseProject/registerUserProcess.php
>   on line 21 0INSERT INTO User (Username, Forename, Surname, Address,
>   PostCode, EmailAddress, Password, DateOfCreation) VALUES ('', '', '',
>   '', '', '', '', '')

As it stands where it says Insert into User ()
User is my table within the database that i would like the information to get inserted into. (all spellings and caps are in the correct place) i am not sure why all the values are blank as it looks like it hasn't gathered the information from the cells provided.

Any helps tips or pointers would be greatly appropriated thanks guys
DateOfCreation is something im messing with atm maybe should take it out as its trying to convert the "i accept terms and conditions" check box to a time stamp to store the date when the user initially created an account. Code is in early stages and does not contain any validation in what so ever can provide code if needed just googled the error message and it seems there's alot of different types for this error message.

```
RegisterUserProcess.php
<?php
    include ("connection.inc.php");
    connect();

        $username = $_POST['Username'];
        $firstName = $_POST['Forename'];
        $lastName = $_POST['Surname'];
        $address = $_POST['Address'];
        $postCode = $_POST['PostCode'];
        $emailAddress = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
        $password = $_POST['Password'];
        $termsConditions = $_POST['DateOfCreation'];

            $sql="INSERT INTO User (Username, Forename, Surname, Address, PostCode, EmailAddress, Password, DateOfCreation)
            VALUES ('$username', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$address', '$postCode', '$emailAddress', '$password', '$termsConditions')";

                mysql_query($sql);
                print("Thank You " +$firstName+" "+$lastName + " You Have Successfully Created An Account!");
                echo $sql;

?>
```

RegisterUser2.php

```
?>
<p><b><h3>Welcome User Please Register</h3></b></p>
    <form action="registerUserProcess.php" id="registerUserForm" method="post" name="registerUserForm">
    *Username:                  
    <input name="username" type="text" size="16" />
    (must contain 8-16 characters with at least 1 number)<br /><br />
    *First name: 
    <input name="firstName" type="text" size="20" />
    *Last name: 
    <input name="lastName" type="text" size="30" />
    <br /><br />
    *Address: 
    <input name="address" type="text" size="50" />
    <br /><br />
    *Post Code:
    <input type="text" name="postCode" size="8" /><br /><br />
    *Email Address: 
    <input name="emailAddress" type="text" size="50" /><br /><br />
    *Password: 
    <input name="password" type="password" size="16" />
    (must contain 8-16 characters with at least 1 number)<br /><br />
    *Confirm Password: 
    <input name="confirmPassword" type="password" size="16" /><br /><br />
    *Accept Terms & Conditions: 
    <input type="checkbox" name="termsConditions" value="yes" /><br /><br />

    <input type="reset" name="resetForm" value="Reset" id="resetForm" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitUser" value="Submit" id="submitUser" />
    </form>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add an isset conditional around your tags (or something similar to that effect)

```
if (isset($DateOfCreation)) {
  // logic here...
}
```

Updated after reference to your updated question, you will need to change your code to the below (do this on every variable)

```
if (isset($_POST['Username'])) { 
  $username = $_POST['Username'];
}
```

Comment: so in pseudo code something along the lines of: if check box ticked then stamp date?

Comment: Hi Graeme, To the above comment, yep correct! 

The issue you are getting is more generic really, PHP has deprecated register globals (you can manually turn it back on but it is not really good from a practicle and coding standards point of view).

You should also really pass your variables through an escaping routine to remove potentially damaging injection. Something along the lines of ``mysql_real_escape_string($var)``.

Comment: I will look into what real escape is and how i can use it. Just sounds abit overwhelming i need to grasp the concept again as i havnt touched web in a couple years and getting it mixed up with java. Thanks for the help

Comment: @michaelotoole This problem has nothing to do with globals - notice provided in the question says everything: "Undefined index". This is proper behavior as there is no field with name `Username`, `Forename`, ...

Comment: the things you said Username Forename Surname are all the correct names of the fields within mysql table within phpmyadmin. Really dont understand where iv gone wrong

Comment: `$_POST` has nothing to do with mysql, phpmyadmin ar ony other database. Read about it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php. You need to have `$_POST` key names the same as `<input>` tag names.

Comment: Hi h4b0, yeah agreed. I didn't see the second part of his question with the form until after my answer. The isset condition is still the way to go if someone fails to enter a field (I was only answering the actual question which had changed during my answer).

The proper answer would be to match the variables up with the form and still use the isset in and around his variables. Turning off display errors on production servers is also recommended.

Comment: so is the isset condition purely for error handling and forcing the user to enter the correct information. and the right thing for me to do now is to look at the code and see if everything matches up name wise yeah ? thanks guys

Comment: Your variables should match up to your form names. Unfortunately I only seen the first half of your code which I based my answer off. The isset condition will stop the Undefined errors (you were basically setting a variable off another variable that didn't exist, the isset functionality will only set the variable if the current variable exists).

First change the names of the POST variables to match those in your form. The isset logic is validation at its very basic level.

Comment: Sorted out my form so it now posts dont think i need the isset conditions unless i can use them for other types of validation but i was going to look at AJAX for validation as this would give the user instantaneous feedback. Thanks for you help everyone

Answer (score 1):

You should add these changes listed below

> Note: $_POST['someelement'] is case-sensitive.

RegisterUserProcess.php

```
<?php
include ("connection.inc.php");
connect();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastname'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $postCode = $_POST['postCode'];
    $emailAddress = $_POST['emailAddress'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
```

And you have never specified input name dateofcreation in your html form. If you want the timestamp you should change dateofcreation field to timestamp and use now() in your query

```
    $termsConditions = $_POST['dateOfCreation'];

        $sql="INSERT INTO User (Username, Forename, Surname, Address, PostCode, EmailAddress, Password, DateOfCreation)
        VALUES ('$username', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$address', '$postCode', '$emailAddress', '$password', 'now()')";

            mysql_query($sql);
            echo "Thank You $firstName $lastName You Have Successfully Created An Account!";
            echo $sql;
```

?>

And your codes needs a lot of changes. It is a suggestion. If you are executing the code in same script then you should use isset

> eg: if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])
>   {
>   some code...
>   }
>   else
>   {
>   html form...
>   }

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some code I can't be sure, but most probably you should change all your occurences of `$Username` to `$_POST['Username']` (if you're using a form with the HTTP POST method), or `$_GET['Username']` (if the data comes from the URL) - `Username` is just an example, of course.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` keys are case-sensitive - you should change `Username` to `username`, `Forename` to `forename`, ... in your php code to match form fields' names.

Comment: on $username = $_POST['Username'];
$username is my text field? and $_POST['Username'] is the row within the phpmyadmin database? if so then the cases are correct? thanks

Comment: No. `$username` is your variable and `$_POST['username']` is a value received from your form (field with name: `username`). These values have nothing to do with your database.

Comment: iv given my text areas a name/id of e.g. username, firstName.. do i need to declear the variables on my RegisterUser2.php page? something like username = get.username? or am i thinking java again sorry

Comment: Your form fields' names are also keys for the `$_POST` array. Since they are case-sensitive, you can't get value of `$_POST['Username']` because there is no field with name `Username` in your form.